# Multi-select value does not store empty values

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working in Magento 1.9 , I have made a multiselect field in system.xml . When i select some fields in multiselect and click on save config it works fine  , but when i did not select any field it should save empty string in DB but it stores the previous values  . 
see my code in system.xml.

```
<onerateserviceOptions>
                            <label>One Rate </label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>FedExSmall/Source_FedExSmallIoneRateServices</source_model>
                            <sort_order>12</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </onerateserviceOptions>
```

Note : That issue only occur in case when i did not select any field . 
Looking for kind help . 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Can you post your system.xml to your question?

Comment: Please post the full xml file.

Comment: Dear xml file is too long , it will be difficult to upload .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add tag `<can_be_empty>` to allow the field storing empty value. So your field should be like this:

```
<onerateserviceOptions>
    <label>One Rate </label>
    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
    <source_model>FedExSmall/Source_FedExSmallIoneRateServices</source_model>
    <sort_order>12</sort_order>
    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</onerateserviceOptions>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Just create function , that will be tranfer "null" to some data or text (for exmpl - "no atribute") .

```
If (....no selected values )
{
  setValue ...
}
```

Etc..